# How to view the link's URL before opening it in a web browser?

Tags: browser, hyperlinks, url

I'd like to see what URL I'm going to visit **before** opening it in my browser. What setting or app allows me to do that?

If there's no such setting, an app that adds an entry to the following box would also be OK.

[image]

PS. Some links trigger [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVKi.png). Long URLs are truncated, so this solution is sub-optimal.

Comment: Have you tried using "Copy Link URL" from the long-press menu (you've got it in your second screenshot) that should copy the link to the clipboard and then you could copy it into any text box or window to view it all. Also "Share Link" from that same menu should copy the URL to whichever app you select, if you send it to something like GMail then it will be pasted into the body of the mail as text (and then its only one "back" press to get back to your original mail once you've viewed it).

Comment: @GAThrawn That menu is only available on some links. The links in the "xkcd Browser" app, for example, only shows the "Complete action using" dialog.

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to view a URL launched from an intent (which is what 99% of apps do in this case). But you can download (or create) an app that accepts URL intents but doesn't load them but shows them to you in some interface or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: After using my original solution for a while, I came to the conclusion that it does not satisfy my needs: Using it to see and use the link URL took too much time.
So I developed a new Android app with a single purpose, namely:

- Copying the link to the clipboard, and
- Display the link target in a toast.

The app is available in Google Play as **Copy Link to Clipboard** (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.robwu.copylink); below are two screenshots of the app in action.

[image: Complete action using: Browser / Copy Link to Clipboard / Firefox Beta] [image: '(link)' copied to clipboard.]

---

<sup>Original answer below</sup>

I figured out that I used the wrong keywords. Searches for "URL preview", "link preview", "view link", etc. didn't yield anything useful. So, I went to look for URL unshortener apps.

The [Unshorten It](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leocardz.url.unshortener) app by LeoCardz (Leonardo Cardoso)

- Adds an entry to the contextmenu of each link.
- Adds an option to the "Share Link" menu.
- Shows up in the URL intent screen.

Furthermore, it is fast, the UI looks great and it doesn't contain any ads or nagging donate requests.

One minor issue: One cannot directly visit the URL without first tapping on the "Unshorten" button. After tapping that button, the URL is resolved (ie. unshortened if needed), and the result is displayed below the blue button. From there, you can share it, or open it in another browser, or just go back to the original app.

[image]

(I've evaluated two other apps, [Unshorten](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teaandtoys.unshorten) by Tea and Toys and [Short URL Evaluator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.nicolassmith.urlevaluator) by Nicolas Smith, but they didn't show up at the URL intent screen, which was a minimal requirement to me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found [URLCheck](https://github.com/TrianguloY/UrlChecker), an open-source app that is available in both [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.trianguloy.urlchecker/) and [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trianguloy.urlchecker).  It registers itself as a browser (so it shows up in the URL intent menu or you can set it as your device's default browser), shows you the link, and then gives you a menu to open it in any "browser" on your device other than URLCheck itself.  URLCheck also has a bunch of optional features you can choose to enable, including unshortening.