# Append a string before opening external URLs

Tags: browser, intents, url

I frequently read news articles shared on social media.

A lot of times, these articles are full of advertising and other irritating elements. I use a service that strips just the content and formats the article in a nice presentation.

I want to automate copying and pasting those links. Basically I want to be able to click on a link on apps and have an option that attaches `service.com/` before that URL and then opens it.

#### What I currently do

- Long click the link on the social (non-browser) app
- Share using a clipboard copier
- Open Chrome
- Type `service.com/` and paste the original URL.

#### What I want to achieve

- Click on the link on a non-browser app
- Open `service.com/original-url.com/etc` on a browser

#### Some ideas:

- A really simple app that registers a web intent, simply appends `http://service.com/` to the beginning of the URL, and opens it on the browser. Unfortunately, I know zero Android programming.
- An app that allows you to register custom intents and add custom actions to it. Is there such a thing? I was able to find [those](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50504/22441) which are close, but not the same thing.

Comment: Pity chrome for Android doesn't have extensions...